# Parsing PHP Issue - fopen() not working correctly for CSV File

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing

I can parse a CSV file and create Insert statements 100% correct when a CSV file is accessible via URL. The issue is that the code does not work when I use use `fopen` on a URL ending in `..format=csv`.

Is there anything I am missing in the code for this to work?

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";  
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "player";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


 $f_pointer=fopen("URL-format=csv","r"); 


 $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE scores";
 $conn->query($sql);


while(! feof($f_pointer)){
   $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
$sql="INSERT INTO     scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('$ar[0]','$ar[1]','$ar[2]','$ar[3]','$ar[4]')";
$conn->query($sql); 
  echo $sql;
 echo "<br>";
    }
 ?>
```

This is the error message:

```
>root@MorryServer:/# php testing.php
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /testing.php on line 21
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /testing.php on line 21
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /testing.php on line 21
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 21
    INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values(???   UtUehOE_ZUzUAfAakQ87dsLbM.csvu??O????_a?t.????s??-??P?蜗+?L?r???ן??? Mj???g<?ӛ????_7??Q?D?Y?R?e?c','','','','')<br>PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in   /testing.php on line 21
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /testing.php on line 21
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 21
    INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('   ??R?<???M??oCQ??0?  P????[?*?q??EF?iB????','?EJsM???','','','')<br>PHP Notice:  Undefined  offset: 2 in /testing.php on line 21
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /testing.php on line 21
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 21
    4n c?%???o??'??q?wĠ!f1?)?d)ΐ???᡾???z0?*total)values('R:
                                       ??','?g?ٓ4tG9????fd???*???','','','')   <br>PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 21 
       INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('m?``???)??VZg?\{???@?P?}???gY9y?p?TA=ˌ','????@^Q?I~FR??%g?? 
                                 *%;?M??.?&`??m?e cZy!????','4?xI??','#?????"}?.????u??d^????-e?dF?B','')<br>PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /testing.php on line 21
       PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 21
       INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('罡?m??7?&?ɣ
                                                                ?g)??L3??l??T2?e[?v?
]!?????xm??ѧB?7?ļ?J?????ۋ?bA?»O?Y?4e?O??O?
cl??;???9-bZ?bط??Rk*t?????Ƣ??V??9??죨?\?۴ B??ԅ?T?a?OR? 3??P??????2~?}?F?8??c??LK@?(????Ns%T1??i]=M???=?????+??)W#{Z?b?S)μ???W??','?3vK?qZ?D?7mE/T?
                                                                  ?ѡ????5?~SMl?bwɿ8J?ؾ>??1Q?/e?ifäs/U?D????'YI??m;NU?%ی?fx??٦?x#??Ù??_??_??O????e??{M???e?v?E??~?)????_??B??I??X?','','')<br>PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /testing.php on line 21
      PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /testing.php on line 21
      PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /testing.php on line 21
      PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 21
      INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('??w՛"???B???Ep??  DXҖ4:?Z?oU<?`???w??"?*?Ϛ???/??'7Ɂ?;q"?*?2?E?65??S4
                                       ^??"?<҃
                                             pl??}?g?Ksw?'xI?x?R??8[??%d???  0-kp??="D??r}J?־?g??','','','','')<br>PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /testing.php on line 21
     PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /testing.php on line 21
      PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 21
      INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('v??Mrpqӳq????x??m??z?Z?ɮ??}R͘???3t?:\0YxOyLv8?ؠi?Mi??<?>?T?KN?<?j??.?ZB?','???c?R>???R??i????b?Ģ????Nb??b<V>鄪???(׽??$?ɓ(????L>??(????Ƿ'?."?t??q?f꼪?\????N?IH?ӡ?;?Y?iO4J??Xʤ9??Ă?5?RUb    \V.?;?????2??QN????????+??MX???F?k?*h?Olr?Q$?&^9H?v}K?F??8@G?y?T?Ԯ???W?1?{??<???ܷN?b^V8
       ?T?????\?nv4l?j??}???(?','','','')<br>PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:    2 in /testing.php on line 21
        PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /testing.php on line 21  
        PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 21
         INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('`??wp??g???????B?    u?SS??x?a^hKhv???51?JԸ8S???5zQ6?숵?`ntn?C*VMk?ؔ~|????Pw?)?IF?g?|MCt?gS????"V    ?KXf>?^?6?]???????xW?W???gێ!??d?QoH??]?!??ia??`ͨ?>?-?h?ki?K ƅ?? ?!ZQ???t???    O???`??3??u??P??c܁?R?g???E?B3????@;????~?????8Gc?;?$sI?z??"??R5??N?;вX[?^?    Aȃj??i??d','?[??0GUH?ٷ???c?*???Jl?V??a?j??lă?N:?&z?nL???m??=t??@W?O?:?    S??????mPY??v?a똺?????P?p?=?#???]???ow?????GPp','','','')<br>
```

Comment: Can you show the entire URL?

Comment: Maybe clean up the error output a little bit too - just so it's easier for the community to read?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not getting values for $ar[0],$ar[1],$ar[2] etc, so, your are getting errors.

try this, to know, how to open a .csv file, read the contents and inserting into respective columns of the database.

```
   $row = 1;
   if (($handle = fopen("xxxxxxxxx.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";   
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $blackpowder = $data;
        $dynamit = implode(";", $blackpowder);
        $pieces = explode(";", $dynamit);
        $col1 = $pieces[0];
        $col2 = $pieces[1];
        $col3 = $pieces[2];
        $col4 = $pieces[3];
        $col5 = $pieces[5];
        mysql_query("
            INSERT INTO `xxxxxx` 
                (`xxx`,`xxx`,`xxx`,`xxxx`,`xxx`) 
            VALUES 
                ('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."')
        ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while (!feof($f_pointer))` to read a file. The EOF flag isn't set until **after** you try to read at the end of file. So you're reading an extra time, which returns `false`, and when you try to use that as an array you get errors.

Change the loop to:

```
while ($ar = fgetcsv($f_pointer)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I get the following error now PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: fp in /testing.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /testing.php on line 17

Comment: Why does my code not work with a URL with a  .format=csv ending. It's odd and i've spent 5hours on this error :/ . Thanks Barmar for helping

Comment: PHP doesn't care about the URL ending. It just sends it to the server, and it's up to the server to recognize that as meaning that it should return the data in a particular format. Are you sure that's how the server you're using works?

Comment: Usually, parameters are after `?`, e.g. `URL?format=csv`

Comment: Same issue. PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /testing.php on line 18
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /testing.php on line 18
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 18
INSERT INTO golfscores(pos,name,thur,score,round)values(' ??R?<???M??oCQ??0?P????[?C}"???OS?('ۢ?2??O??? OedQ?d?FwJY?4?c?*?q??EF?iB????','?EJsM???','','','')<br>PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in /testing.php on line 18

Comment: Are you sure the server is returning CSV?

Comment: When I visit the URL in the code, a .csv is downloaded is that what u mean?

Comment: I did a print out there of data and this is what i get - looks corrupt or something <p> 2 fields in line 3: <br /></p>
4n c?%???o??'??q?wĠ!f1?)?d)ΐ???᡾???z0?*
                                       ??<br />
?g?ٓ4tG9????fd???*???<br />
<p> 4 fields in line 4: <br /></p>
m?``???)??VZg?\{???@?P?}???gY9y?p?TA=ˌ<br />
????@^Q?I~FR??%g?? 
                   *%;?M??.?&`??m?e cZy!????<br />
4?xI??<br />
#?????"}?.????u??d^????-e?dF?B<br />

Comment: That's not CSV, it's HTML.

Comment: Sorry those br tags were in my debug it's csv. I'll look at the encoding on the server i guess